# Unhandled exception at Access violation reading location using refprop.dll call

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I'm writing a C++ application using Visual Studio Express 2013. My application makes calls to a module called refprop.dll. However, the call to SETUPdll fails sometimes (about half the time). Other times it works perfectly. My code is like so.

in refprop1.h

```
typedef  void(__stdcall *fp_SETUPdllTYPE)(long &, char*, char*, char*, long &, char*, long, long, long, long);
fp_SETUPdllTYPE SETUPdll;
```

in Main .cpp

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "refprop1.h"


// Some constants...

const long refpropcharlength = 255;
const long filepathlength = 255;
const long lengthofreference = 3;
const long errormessagelength = 255;
const long numparams = 72;
const long maxcoefs = 50;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    // First create a pointer to an instance of the library
    // Then have windows load the library.
    HINSTANCE RefpropdllInstance;
    RefpropdllInstance = LoadLibrary("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\REFPROP\\REFPROP.DLL");
    //point the function
    SETUPdll = (fp_SETUPdllTYPE)GetProcAddress(RefpropdllInstance, "SETUPdll");

    //setup variables
    long i, ierr;
    char hf[refpropcharlength*ncmax], hrf[lengthofreference + 1],
    herr[errormessagelength + 1], hfmix[refpropcharlength + 1];

    i = 3;
    strcpy_s(hf, "D:\\East101\\Adri\\devprojects\\theSeed\\RefProp\\fluids\\METHANE.FLD|ETHANE.FLD|BENZENE.FLD");
    strcpy_s(hfmix, "D:\\East101\\Adri\\devprojects\\theSeed\\RefProp\\fluids\\HMX.BNC");
    strcpy_s(hrf, "DEF");
    strcpy_s(herr, "Ok");

   //call the setup - this SOMETIMES throws an error: Unhandled exception.....
   SETUPdll(i, hf, hfmix, hrf, ierr, herr, refpropcharlength*ncmax, refpropcharlength,lengthofreference, errormessagelength);
```

Edit:
I've also noticed that the problem only occurs for the SETUPdll call. The other calls can be made successfully (but meaningless because you need to call SETUPdll first).

Also is there any way to debug the dll itself/peer into what's going on in there?

Comment: Are you building your project x86 or x64?  If you're building 64 bit, you may want to look at your `LoadLibrary` call since it looks to be loading a 32 bit dll.

Comment: The intermittent nature of the failure, rules out the architecture mismatch. What is _refprop_? Where did the _refprop1.h_ file come from? Is there a public API that the dll offers (like the `SETUPdll` function header), or you guessed the signature (cause if it's the latter it might be the root cause of your problem). The error is that the function is trying to access an area outside of the "allowed" memory.

Comment: Nevermind, I found some references at [NIST](http://www.nist.gov/srd/upload/REFPROP9.PDF). However there, `refprop2.h` is mentioned.

Comment: Ok, downloaded and installed [RefProp Mini](http://www.boulder.nist.gov/div838/theory/refprop/MINIREF/MINIREF.EXE) which is a free minimal distribution. Judging on the paths you have inserted in the snippet, I assume you have the full (paid) version (also I only have _METHANE.FLD_), meaning that you should also have _refprop2.h_ (and presumably _refprop.lib_). Anyway (whether you have the paid version or you're simply trying to "hack" the free version), where did those constants came from? and what is `ncmax`'s value?

Comment: @CristiFati Yes I have the paid version but it's an older version. Current version is 9.1 and I'm using 9.0. The code snippets came from the demo files that came with the installation. The error occurs without me making any changes to the supplied code. I've downloaded refprop2.h (it doesn't come with refprop.lib) and the only difference in the  SETUPdll is as follows:

Comment: @CristiFati the only difference in the SETUPdll is first 2 long arguments are by ref instead of by value. you can get the examples here  http://www.boulder.nist.gov/div838/theory/refprop/LINKING/Linking.htm#CApplications   ncmax is 20 I left that part out.

Comment: @theB I'm building with Win32. I'm pretty sure the dll I'm using is 32 bit because a new version of the dll exists as refprp64.dll.

Comment: As i already said your app and the dll, reside in the 32bit area. Now,   NIST are pretty security paranoid (they are the ones that invented and "pushed" in production FIPS), and their terms are pretty innegociable.

Comment: Ok, give me the .dll (and additional files (ethane and benzene files)) hopefully without hurting yourself, (but can you explain to the community).

Comment: Thank you. Will let you know the results of my investigation.

Comment: I didn't find anything that would clearly indicate me why this is happening. I am going to post an answer with some changes that your code should "suffer" and also my tests results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@CristiFati gives a really good explanation for what is going on.

As a workaround (ugly but works for me):

RefpropdllInstance is a member of a class (RefPropPack) which handles the setup and calls. 
I'm now catching the access violation error (See details here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1deeycx5(v=vs.80).aspx). I've tried reloading the dll (FreeLibrary(), set pointers to NULL, reload and remap functions and recall SETUPdll) but did not solve the problem. So instead, when the error occurs I just delete the RefPropPack object and reinstantiate/setup it. It may take more than one try but will eventually succeed.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things about the code (I also ended the `main` function from your snippet):

- When calling *Windows API* (or any other) functions, **never** ignore the return codes, otherwise you might end up having hard to find problems, like the current one. But in our case there were no such errors.
- I modified a little bit the constants (see the comments in my snippet). In some cases that could also trigger hard to find problems, but again not the case here.
- Your code didn't work (when it wasn't failing with *Acces violation*), because the file paths were incorrect. Here's the error that it used to return: *[SETUP error 101] error in opening file for component #  2; filename = (ETHANE.FLD                                                                      ).* I fixed that by specifying the full paths.

Note that I also downloaded the other code from NIST, but it was too complex and it requires stuff that I don't have installed, so I focused on your code (I even copied the files onto the same paths to have an environment as close as possible to yours).

A personal opinion on *RefProp*: I am not aware of what exactly it does, I know it's a kind of property DB for different chemical substances (most of them part of organic chemistry), but in terms of programming:

Not sure how *refrpop1.h* was born:

- provided by *RefProp* creators
- generated by a tool that inspected the dll and figured out the function signatures

If it's the latter then it's ok, but if it's the former, then it really sucks because (and I only enumerate here the 1st 2 items that bother me the most):

- I couldn't find any documentation on the functions. I don't know what `SETUPdll` does/should do, I don't know what the arguments are/should be, for example I have a strong feeling that only the error text (`herr`) is an output parameter (and if my assumption is correct, all the others should have been `const char *`)
- the codestyle is a mess

So, back to your code (with corrections):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "refprop1.h"


// Some constants...

const long refpropcharlength = 255;
const long lengthofreference = 3;
const long numparams = 72;
const long maxcoefs = 50;
const long ncmax = 20;

const long filepathlength = MAX_PATH;  //Windows defines this constant (260)
const long errormessagelength = 255 + filepathlength;  //Error message contains an error text + a filename
const long hflength = filepathlength * ncmax + ncmax - 1;  //ncmax files + (ncmax - 1) separators ("|")
const long hfmixlength = filepathlength;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    // First create a pointer to an instance of the library
    // Then have windows load the library.
    HMODULE RefpropdllInstance = NULL;
    if ((RefpropdllInstance = LoadLibrary("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\REFPROP\\REFPROP.DLL")) == NULL) {
        printf("Error [%d] loading lib\n", GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }

    //point the function
    if ((SETUPdll = (fp_SETUPdllTYPE)GetProcAddress(RefpropdllInstance, "SETUPdll")) == NULL) {
        printf("Error [%d] getting func\n", GetLastError());
        FreeLibrary(RefpropdllInstance);
        return -2;
    }

    //setup variables
    long i = 3, ierr = 0;
    char hf[hflength + 1], hrf[lengthofreference + 1],
    herr[errormessagelength + 1], hfmix[hfmixlength + 1];

    strcpy_s(hf, "E:\\East101\\Adri\\devprojects\\theSeed\\RefProp\\fluids\\METHANE.FLD|E:\\East101\\Adri\\devprojects\\theSeed\\RefProp\\fluids\\ETHANE.FLD|E:\\East101\\Adri\\devprojects\\theSeed\\RefProp\\fluids\\BENZENE.FLD");
    strcpy_s(hfmix, "E:\\East101\\Adri\\devprojects\\theSeed\\RefProp\\fluids\\HMX.BNC");
    strcpy_s(hrf, "DEF");
    strcpy_s(herr, "Ok");

   //call the setup - this SOMETIMES throws an error: Unhandled exception.....
    // (long &, char*, char*, char*, long &, char*, long, long, long, long);
   SETUPdll(i, hf, hfmix, hrf, ierr, herr, hflength, hfmixlength, lengthofreference, errormessagelength);
   if (ierr != 0) {
       char aux[errormessagelength + 40];
       sprintf(aux, "Error [%d] calling `SETUPdll`(%d): %s\n", ierr, strlen(herr), herr);
       OutputDebugString(aux);
       printf(aux);
   }
   FreeLibrary(RefpropdllInstance);
   printf("Done\n");
   return 0;
}
```

Tests:

- I noticed that the *Access violation* failure happens once at 30 runs in average
- I also noticed that when `hf` didn't have the full paths (so `SETUPdll` was returning error 101) the failure was more often; with the correct paths I did 100 consecutive runs (multiple times) without encountering it. I'm not saying this is a rule, it might be just a coincidence.
- I moved all the code from `main` to a different func and called it from `main` in a loop (1000 iterations), also multiple times, but the failure didn't come up.

So, the final question:

*Do I have a clear answer why the program fails with Access violation (segfault)?*

The answer is: **No**.

However I've checked *REFPROP.DLL* dependencies, and there are only 2: *KERNEL32.DLL* and *USER32.DLL* (no *MSVCR*.DLL*). That means that it has been statically linked to the *VC runtime* (or any C runtime equivalent). On the other hand your executable also has its own VC runtime (how it's linked to it it's not important).

As a consequence, you have 2 C runtimes in your executable (one in the exe and one in the dll). One of a C runtime tasks is **memory management**: how memory (pointers) is being allocated/deallocated (check [malloc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ewkz86d(v=vs.100).aspx)/[free](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/we1whae7(v=vs.100).aspx) functions). In some cases (if the dll code and the exe code are not in "sync"), you might end up allocating a pointer from one runtime and deallocating it from the other, and that could lead to the very behavior that we have here.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Just to address some of your comments:    Refprop calculates properties based on data found in the fluid files. Refprop.h did indeed come from Refrprop themselves. I suppose I'll chuck the setup part in a separate function as you did.     Again, thanks.

Comment: One second: moving the whole thing in a function doesn't guarantee that the error won't come up. I've ran it with the 1000 loop function ~5-6 times and I didn't run into the failure, but maybe I didn't get to the "faulty" run; if I would have ran it another 20 times let's say, maybe once it would fail for every loop call.